# How with javascript change html code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need the following change using javascript:
from:

```
<input id="innn" value="" />
```

to:

```
<input id="innn" value="SOME_VALUE" />
```

I tried this:

```
document.getElementById("innn").setAttribute("value", "189");
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById('innn').value = '152';
```

it worked but it changed only visual on page not the html code and i need to change the code as shown below:

```
<input id="innn" value="" /> --> <input id="innn" value="125" /> --><input id="innn" value="158" />
```

Please help or I must use php like :     `<input id="innn" value="<? php ... ?>" />`    ????

Comment: It actually changes the code, but obviosly it cannot modify the source code from server.

Comment: changes made in client side that mean in your browser not in server stored html code

Comment: Why do you need to change the HTML Markup? Maybe if we know that reason we can give you a solution.

Comment: ok and how / it is posssible modify source code ?? user in bar set up how much month he wants premium javascript show change and i need send it  to pay, i must know what user set up.

Comment: Modifying source code is generally not the best idea. What are you trying to achieve? There may be a better solution.

Comment: I appreciate English is probably not your first language, but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what you're trying to say. Are you trying to create a system where a user can select a monthly payment, and you then want to record what plan they chose, so you can send them an invoice?

Comment: value is an input field value, not any special attribute that you can change and see the change as in code for most of the attributes... its the value what you set for default, or what you read when user types in it.. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp

Comment: ok thanks, now i made it, mayby :D

Answer (score 0):

HTML is what is rendered in order for your browser to know what to show on your page. Once sent by the server it will not change (at least not with basic JavaScript). There are more advanced ways of doing things, but they are not simple. When you call a JavaScript function to change something, it changes it in the DOM, so you will see the change on your screen, but when you click view-source your browser is fetching the original page again from the server to show you. In some browsers they have something called Inspect mode which allows you to see what the HTML looks like right now for your page. In that case it will show the updated code. If you want that when someone clicks view-source and sees `SOME_VALUE` in the value for `id="innn"`, then you would need to use PHP.

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById("innn").value = somevalue